# How do I set labels.restricted / want to restrict the file from Downloading in Google Drive

Tags: php, google-drive-api

Here is the parameter, under `labels.restricted` :

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert

But cannot code it in PHP tried almost everything but still getting error from the google drive API.

```
$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$file->setTitle(TESTFILE);

$file->setRestricted();

$result = $service->files->insert(
  $file,
  array(
    'data' => file_get_contents(TESTFILE),
    'mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream',
    'uploadType' => 'multipart'
    //
    // HERE SHOULD BE THE CODE FOR THE labels.restricted
    //
  )
);
```

Comment: Which error are you getting? Add the error message to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to setRestricted on a Label:

```
$label = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFileLabels();
$label->setRestricted(true);
$file->setLabels($label);
```